# Bug xcode - Iphone 7 sumiu da minha lista derrepente

Tags: ios

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, o iphone 7 sumiu da minha lista no xcode, o que eu faço ? preciso restaurar ele, pois sem ele não posso entregar o projeto.

Comment: Como essa lista é apenas para simular visualizações, são listados apenas resoluções diferentes. Provavel que algum destes aparelhos listados tem a mesma resolução do iphone 7 e por isso não há necessidade de repetir. Pelo que pesquisei é mesma resolução do Iphone 8

Comment: certeza ??????????????

Answer (score 0):

A cada nova atualização do xcode, pode ocorrer esse tipo de alteração, seja pela mudança de resolução (ser igual a outros modelos) ou pela versão default do xcode nao rodar determinado iPhone/iPad.

Vc pode adicionar um novo Simulador para que seja o 7, caso precise realmente, da seguinte forma:

Simulator -> Add Aditional Simulator -> Simulators -> botao "+"
Aí preencher com nome, type e versão que desejar.